# What to use to store the variable locally in the browser to use it for next launch

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am new to web development I am working on program which uses a script in which want to store the final result as intial variable at the time of next launch of .html file.whether I should use cookies or something else
Thank you

Comment: Use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) with Cookies as a fallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `localStorage` like so:

**SET:**

```
localStorage.setItem('myVar', myVarData);
```

**GET:**

```
var value = localStorage.getItem('myVar');
```

or cookies. Utility function from [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp):

**SET:**

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

**GET:**

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends a bit on how you want to use it and what browsers you need to support but in most cases I would use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the values.

localStorage is persistent storage that is local to the given origin (i.e. your URL). It can be used to store data in the form of key/value pairs and it will be kept when the browser is closed and opened.

**Example** To store the value *4711* in a variable called *mySetting* you write

```
localStorage.setItem('mySetting', 4711);
```

Then you can later retrieve the value by

```
var value = localStorage.getItem('mySetting');
```

Comment: <html>
<head><title>Balance Deduction App </title>

<script language = javascript>
Function mb ()
{
  var mb=300;
  var dd=30;
   var nw=mb-dd;
   alert (nw);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad=mb ();>
</body>
</html>

I want to store the value of nw and later want to equate it to mb.
How to implement localstorage here.